# Net::HTTP SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: ruby

I have Googled this to death and gone through the related posts on this question.  I don't think it's a Rails / Ruby issue but not sure where to go next.

```
irb(main):007:0> Net::HTTP.get_response("http://www.apple.com","")
SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
from /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
```

No network issues otherwise.  apple.com loads fine in a browser.  This is in a rails app in development on my local machine.  Looking to pull a JSON request via a third party API. All Net::HTTP requests film like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass an [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) object to the `get_response` method so that it has `scheme` and `host` etc. info in it:

```
URI('http://www.apple.com').host
# => "www.apple.com"
URI('http://www.apple.com').scheme
# => "http"
```

So, to solve your problem, do it this way:

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI("http://www.apple.com"))
# => #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

To get the response body, do this:

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI("http://www.apple.com")).body
```

See the [get_response](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get_response) documentation for more details.

Comment: Read the docs!!? ;)  That worked and thanks for the explanation.  The example I was given didn't have the URI call.  Thanks